# shortcuts / functionallity for Custom CSS editor in Elementor

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, elementor

I searched the help files and the web, but I did not get any reference for the Custom CSS Editor in Elementor. I realized, there are some shortcuts e.g. to skip to next / previous findings of siblings of highlighted text. I somehow collapsed brackets today, but I do not know how. Is there any documentation which shortcuts are supported in Custom CSS field?

In other words for better understanding: When I edit CSS code in the Custom CSS field, there are different shortcuts possible which seem similar to other editors like Sublime.

E.g. when I select a text, I can jump up and down to the next similar term with Command + Shift +g

https://pasteboard.co/GEIqwudPQeu6.jpg

I realized there are other shortcuts, too, as I accidentally collapsed a bracket to give a better code overview. But I cannot remember the shortcut. Is there a table anywhere, which shortcuts will be supported by Custom CSS Editor?

Elementor is missing a lot of OS X shortcuts anyway, too, like delete objects in navigator etc. And support staff from in Elementor was no help so far ...